# Transferring sensitive information from javascript to rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am currently writing a Firefox extension that will sync your tab sessions across different instances of the browser.  I am using a Ruby on Rails web application to sync the different URLS for each user.

The Firefox extension is using Javascript to parse out the current websites that are open.  I need to send a user's login name, password, and the list of open URLs to the Rails application securely from Javascript.

Is there a way to transfer this information to the Rails app from Javascript without compromising the password?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason it wouldn't work to use https?

Comment: Through something like a xmlhttprequest POST?  I'm sorry, I'm very new to both Javascript and transferring securely over a network.  I really don't want to mess this one up.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can call over SSL using XML Request. 
Easy enough to test and see ...